# How does Pandas allocate memory for merge/joins internally?

Tags: pandas

How do internal Pandas functions allocate memory for operations that have an uncertain number of output rows?  For example when joining two dataframes the number of output rows depends on the values of the inputs.  You don't really know how many rows there will be until you have completed the join.  Does Pandas perform two passes?  Does it use a dynamic data structure?  If so, which?

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-design/blob/master/source/internal-architecture.rst#what-is-blockmanager-and-why-does-it-exist

Comment: https://krbnite.github.io/Memory-Efficient-Windowing-of-Time-Series-Data-in-Python-2-NumPy-Arrays-vs-Pandas-DataFrames/

Answer (score 0):

Pandas uses a [Resizable Array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-of-dynamic-array-in-python/) to allocate memory for operations that have an uncertain number of output rows.

a Resizable Array is implemented as a numpy array with a dynamic size. When an operation such as a join is performed, the Resizable Array starts with an initial size and then dynamically grows as needed to accommodate the results of the operation. This is done in a single pass and no intermediate data structure is created.

The resizing process is efficient because numpy arrays are contiguous in memory, which means that resizing can be done by allocating a larger block of memory, copying the existing data into the new memory block, and then deallocating the old memory block. This avoids the overhead of constantly allocating and deallocating memory.